# cordova/ionic simple css transitions not smooth

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic 2 and trying to perform a very simple css transition on a certain element:

```
.element {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  width : 200px;
}

.transition {
   width : 500px;
}
```

This looks great on the browser, but when tested on device (iPad) it looks very flickery and not smooth at all.
Is something wrong with my iPad or this is a known issue?

How can I make things go smooth?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your iPad doesn't have as much CPU resources as your PC. One way of making it smoother is making the transition longer. And fade transitions are faster than resizing ones.